# Getting from memory address to function in source

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory-address

with the tool Process Explorer I know that my process hangs at a special function
myexe.exe+0x1b5773

is there a way to get to the exact function if I have the pdb available?
Or must there be a .map file for this information?

I know I can attach to the exe with a debugger, but this is now always a option if the problem occures on a not developer machine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Process Explorer

This can be done in Process Explorer itself under `Options|Configure symbols...`:

1. Choose `dbghelp.dll`
2. Set the symbol path

   ```
   SRV*c:\debug\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;c:\mysymbols
   ```

But this may not be very convenient for your customer.

A safer and typically more user friendly way:

1. Right click the process
2. Choose `Create dump | Create Minidump...`
3. Select a file name
4. Let the customer send you the dump so that you can analyze it.

With a dump, you can't do anything wrong and even weeks later, it can still be analyzed, which you can't in case of transient data just displayed by Process Explorer for a moment.

### WinDbg

You can do it in WinDbg like this:

1. open the executable in question but **as a dump file**
2. `.symfix`
3. `.sympath+ <your PDB path>`
4. `.reload`
5. `ln myexe.exe+0x1b5773`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
This is great!